# OpenVPN connections - Status via Python? [Windows 10]

Tags: python, openvpn

I'm a happy OpenVPN user. I am just not happy with the logging.

**I need two things:**

1. check whether a connection has been established or not.
2. location of the connection. For example: Los Angeles, United States.

Any idea how I can retrieve these information via Python?
And without using a website?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: To find location of IP address you should use any public website or use huge database (few gigabytes).

Comment: The .ovpn files already contain the country name. Is there a way to use Python to check the country I'm connected to? E.g.: France.ovpn.

Comment: I am not happy with the suggestion. Please help guys.